# How can I display this HTML/PHP table in rows conditionally (Event Espresso)?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, html-table

I'm using a WordPress plugin called [Event Expresso](https://eventespresso.com/) and they have an [addon](https://eventespresso.com/wiki/events-table-view-template-add-on/) that outputs a table, I'm trying to customize the output of that table (which is perfectly doable)

**Here is the code we have so far:** https://codeshare.io/29p1b0

The problem is the following:

[image: all columns]

We want the data (except date) to accommodate to rows but the event names are all in on column, we want each event to fit in each date, our main concerns is getting each event in a row format.

Comment: Your question should directly include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be lines 20-23 and line 25 where you're running a loop and displaying the venue name for each post in the table's header. You can remove those lines of code and the table rows will snap into place. Then you can also change line 24 to display something for the table header content for that second column.